# Action to fill Date picker automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

[image]

Can anyone help me to setup an action to fill this datepicker automatically?

This is the source code

```
 $('.date_of_birth').datepicker({
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    endDate: new Date(dtJS),
    startDate: '-100y',
    autoclose: true,
    startView: 2
 });
```

And which program can I use to setup this function?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code**

adding `minViewMode: "years"` option help you to generate datepicker as shown in your image.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var dtJS="2017-06-28";
    $('.date_of_birth').datepicker({
    format: "yyyy",
    endDate: new Date(dtJS),
    startDate: '-100y',
    autoclose: true,
    minViewMode: "years",
    startView: 1
 });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var dtJS="2017-06-28";
    $('.date_of_birth').datepicker({
    format: "yyyy",
    endDate: new Date(dtJS),
    startDate: '-100y',
    autoclose: true,
    minViewMode: "years",
    startView: 1
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker3.min.css">
<input class="date_of_birth" type="text" />
```